# merge python dictionary based on values

Tags: python

I have the following python list of dictionaries:

```
list= [{'_id': 'EF25E6D', 'RecordSets': [{'Name': '@', 'TTL': '', 'Type': '', 'Value': 'ns1.netnames.net.'}]},{'_id': 'EF25E6D', 'RecordSets': [{'Name': '@', 'TTL': '', 'Type': '', 'Value': 'ns2.netnames.net.'}]},
{'_id': 'EF25E6D', 'RecordSets': [{'Name': '@', 'TTL': '', 'Type': '', 'Value': 'ns5.netnames.net.'}]},{'_id': 'EF25E6D', 'RecordSets': [{'Name': '@', 'TTL': '', 'Type': '', 'Value': 'ns6.netnames.net.'}]},
{'_id': '7E00EAC', 'RecordSets': [{'Name': '@', 'TTL': '', 'Type': '', 'Value': 'ns1.netnames.net.'}]},{'_id': '7E00EAC', 'RecordSets': [{'Name': '@', 'TTL': '', 'Type': '', 'Value': 'ns2.netnames.net.'}]},
{'_id': '7E00EAC', 'RecordSets': [{'Name': '@', 'TTL': '', 'Type': '', 'Value': 'ns5.netnames.net.'}]},{'_id': '7E00EAC', 'RecordSets': [{'Name': '@', 'TTL': '', 'Type': '', 'Value': 'ns6.netnames.net.'}]}]
```

how do i group these so that i get a unique _id and a list of the record sets?

any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show your attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, this looks like a job for [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
for item in records: # make sure your list is not named "list"; better use "records"!
    dd[item["id"]].append(item["RecordSets"])
```

The result is a dictionary-like object that contains

```
{'7E00EAC': [[{'Name': '@',
    'TTL': '',
    'Type': '',
    'Value': 'ns1.netnames.net.'}],
  [{'Name': '@',
    'TTL': '',
    'Type': '',
    'Value': 'ns2.netnames.net.'}],
  [{'Name': '@',
    'TTL': '',
    'Type': '',
    'Value': 'ns5.netnames.net.'}],
  [{'Name': '@',
    'TTL': '',
    'Type': '',
    'Value': 'ns6.netnames.net.'}]],
 'EF25E6D': [[{'Name': '@',
    'TTL': '',
    'Type': '',
    'Value': 'ns1.netnames.net.'}],
  [{'Name': '@',
    'TTL': '',
    'Type': '',
    'Value': 'ns2.netnames.net.'}],
  [{'Name': '@',
    'TTL': '',
    'Type': '',
    'Value': 'ns5.netnames.net.'}],
  [{'Name': '@',
    'TTL': '',
    'Type': '',
    'Value': 'ns6.netnames.net.'}]]
}
```

If all your record sets are only one item long (as in your example), use

```
    dd[item["id"]].append(item["RecordSets"][0])
```

to avoid an unnecessarily nested list.